# Is it possible to strafe/sidestep?

Tags: heretic

Is it possible to sidetep or strafe in Heretic? Currently I'm playing using `Cursors`, <kbd>ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>space</kbd>.

I'm struggling to avoid enemy projectiles without the use of a strafe. I've avoided using the mouse as it feels strange to not have free look.

I don't see anything for this in the options. Will I need to modify my config files or similar to enable this functionality?

Comment: Isn't there like a button for it? Maybe press alt and try moving left or right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If my memory is correct you should be able to strafe using the 'STRAFE ON' key which default was on ALT for most of the games of that period.

i.e. press ALT + LEFT.

Comment: Awesome, I'll give this a go tonight :)

Comment: Did you try Q or E ? Or to look in the settings ?

Comment: Yes, I did look in the settings. As per the question.
"I don't see anything for this in the options."

Comment: I will check tonight if I can find some way to install Heretic ... but look for a strafe modifier key in the settings if I am incorrect I will amend my answer.

Comment: Thanks, but as I've marked your question as accepted that means I tried it and it worked. So your work here is done! :D